# Error after running mapper.py locally in terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, hadoop

I have just started learning Hadoop. I tried to run a simple mapreduce job on it, but before that I tried to check it locally. But its returning error. Kindly suggest any solution to it. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

SO the code is written in gedit, and is ad follows.

```
import sys

   for line in sys.stdin:

   line = line.strip()

   words = line.split()

   for word in words:

       print '%s\t%s' %(word,1)
```

Then I write the below command in terminal to check if mapper is working fine

```
maitreyee@bharti-desktop:~$ echo "foo faa" | /home/maitreyee/Documents/mapper.py
```

and the terminal returns the following error:

```
/home/maitreyee/Documents/mapper.py: line 1: import: command not found
/home/maitreyee/Documents/mapper.py: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `line'
/home/maitreyee/Documents/mapper.py: line 5: `line = line.strip()'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the top of your script. Add something like this (whichever python makes sense for your machine):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Here I use the system python under `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Thanks bud!! I thought it was just a comment and didnt bother to write it ><><><><

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line is needed because you have several versions of Python installed, /usr/bin/env will ensure the interpreter used is the first one on your environment's $PATH.

If you want more to know about writing map reduce code in python, you can follow this
 [tutorial](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/&ei=cP1gPR9U&lc=en-IN&geid=7&s=1&m=296&ts=1443599014&sig=APONPFmCKxW8VCNZZl56uF3VVJ3aByn0Bw)!